# UnityでPhotonとOVRInputを使用したオブジェクトの表示・非表示のトグルが一度しか機能しない

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity 2022.3.14 と PUN 2 を使用して、Meta Quest向けのVRマルチプレイヤーゲームを開発しています。プレイヤーがAボタンを押すことで、EyeGazeという名前の子オブジェクト（視線ビームを示す3Dオブジェクト）の表示と非表示を切り替える機能を実装しようとしています。

以下のスクリプトをEyeGazeオブジェクトにアタッチしましたが、Aボタンを最初に押したときにはオブジェクトの表示・非表示が切り替わるのに成功します。しかし、二度目以降のボタンの押下ではオブジェクトの状態が切り替わらなくなります。OculusのSDKはプロジェクトに正しく組み込まれており、他の入力は問題なく機能しています。

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class ToggleObject : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    private GameObject eyeGaze;

    void Start()
    {
        eyeGaze = this.gameObject;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.One))
            {
                eyeGaze.SetActive(!eyeGaze.activeSelf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

コードにはPhotonViewがアタッチされており、IsMineを使用してローカルプレイヤーの入力のみを処理しているはずです。eyeGazeは、ゲームオブジェクト自体の表示状態を切り替えるためにSetActiveを使っています。

この問題を解決するために、どのようなデバッグ手順を取ればよいか、または何か見落としている可能性がある部分があれば指摘していただけますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> eyeGaze.SetActive(!eyeGaze.activeSelf);

この処理で、自分自身を SetActive(false) で無効化してしまうと、以降で、void Update() が呼ばれなくなってしまいます。

よって、別のオブジェクトで photonView の状態を監視し、そのオブジェクト上の処理で eyeGaze.SetActive により表示非表示を制御すると良いと思います。